# Where should questions about MathJaX go?

Tags: discussion, migration, mathjax

I'm asking this from the perspective of the TeX-SX site.  Basically, we don't want them unless they are really questions about TeX and not about MathJaX.  In particular, questions about configuring MathJaX, about installing MathJaX, and about how to do something particular in MathJaX, are all off-topic on TeX-SX.  The reason being that MathJaX does not use TeX and so expertise in TeX does not help at all in answering questions such as those above.  Although we have a MathJaX tag, the phrasing hopefully makes this clear: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info

To be *absolutely* clear, it isn't that we have anything against MathJaX.  It is because the expertise that exists on TeX-SX has no relevance whatsoever for helping people with MathJaX and therefore it is in the questioner's best interests to find a better place to ask their question.

But we occasionally get questions about it, and also get questions migrated from other sites about it.  Where should we redirect those questions on this network, if anywhere?  Our tag, linked above, suggests the main Stack Overflow site, but the most recent migration (and the reason why I'm asking this) came from there.  And was migrated after it had been answered by the lead developer of MathJaX!

Stack Overflow version: [MathJax and LaTeX \definecolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581495/mathjax-and-latex-definecolor?noredirect=1)

Comment: I think I'd say 'very little relevance': some MathJax questions do come down to (La)TeX-related conventions or input and can be answered on TeX-SE.

Answer (score 12):

I was disappointed to see that migration as well.  I saw someone had suggested it and almost said that it would be closed as soon as it hit TeX-SE, which is just what happened.

The correct place to ask MathJax questions is the [MathJax user's form](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users).  This is not a StackExchange site, so it isn't easy to migrate them there, but you can certainly suggest they ask them there instead.

Comment: Whether or not there is a site here that is a reasonable place to ask, that link is certainly worth making a note of.  Thanks.

Comment: That means I shouldn't ask MathJax question on the LA-TEX se site?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused, correct, unless they are about TeX syntax or other actual TeX issues rather than MathJax ones.

Answer (score 7):

Davide is (unsurprisingly) correct that the best place for MathJax questions is the MathJax help forum/mailing list. Within the Stack Exchange network I think the best place is Stack Overflow tagged [mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax).

Comment: Yes, there's a distinction between the 100% best place, and the *locally* best place.  One nice thing about the SE network is that if you're already here, it's easy to join other sites.